# Locksmith Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on setting up my application with Locksmith and I have the following code:

```
let kAttrAccount = "Driver"

class User {
  var token: String?

  init () {
    let account = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(kAttrAccount)
    if let account = account {
      self.token = account["token"]
      print(self.token)
    }
  }

  convenience init (token: String) {
    let _ = try? Locksmith.saveData(["token": token], forUserAccount: kAttrAccount)
    self.init()
  }
}
```

When I try to build my app for iOS, I get an error at the line `self.token = account["token"]`, I get the error `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'`.

To test, I threw the following code into a Playground and it works fine:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Locksmith

let _ = try? Locksmith.saveData(["token": "something"], forUserAccount: "GoDriver")

let account = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("GoDriver")

if let account = account {
  account["token"]
}
```

Comment: self.token = account["token"] as? String

Comment: "To test, I threw the following code into a Playground and it works fine" Because what you tested in the Playground was not the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `account` is a `[String:AnyObject]`, so `account["token"]` is an AnyObject. You cannot assign an AnyObject to a `String?`, which is what your `self.token` is. You would have to cast it. Example:

```
let account = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(kAttrAccount)
if let account = account {
    if let tok = account["token"] as? String {
        self.token = tok
        print(self.token)
    }
}
```

The above can be condensed, but I'm showing you a very full form so that you understand what's going on.

Comment: I'll grant you this: it's not a very helpful error message from the Swift compiler. But there's nothing new there. :(

Comment: That worked, but now I intermittently have the account value come back nil. Any idea of why that might happen conceptually?

Comment: That would be a whole 'nother question! Your question was about _syntax_ (compilation). We solved that. Now you're having a problem with how Locksmith _works_ (runtime). So if you have a new question, ask a new question; don't "leech" by coming back to the answerer in a comment.